# Physical significance of a fractional operator

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there any physical significance of the operator $(-\Delta)^s\pm \Delta$ when $0<s<1.$ I would like to know if there is any real life applications other than in pure mathematics.

Comment: you are looking for physics applications of the fractional Laplacian? there many, as a quick Google search will reveal...

Comment: I know about fractional Laplacian, but I want to know about the fractional Laplacian with a Laplacian perturbation.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of combination arises, e.g., when studying the transition between long-range and short-range models of statistical mechanics, like with Ising spins.
There was some controversy about this, see, e.g., ["Influence of long-range interactions on the critical behavior of the Ising model"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/101/56003) by Blanchard, Picco and Rajabpour, and ["The crossover region between long-range and short-range interactions for the critical exponents"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-014-1081-0) by Brezin, Parisi and Ricci-Tersenghi. As far as know, this has been resolved recently, see ["Long-range critical exponents near the short-range crossover"](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.241601) by Behan, Rastelli, Rychkov and Zan.

I think the main difficulty is the presence of two competing renormalization group fixed points, one with the standard Laplacian (the short-range fixed point) and one with the fractional one (the long-range fixed point). RG computations trying to analyze this competition would typically involve such sums/linear combinations of the two kinds of Laplacians.